# PowerShell: Copy-Item Cannot find path

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I'm trying to get [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) to copy files from a remote computer (on which I have admin rights through [AD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory)) to the local computer.
It fails in the strangest place. Here's a snippet of the script:

```
    $configs = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Filter "*.config" $serverUNCPath 
foreach($config in $configs){
    $config_target_dir = $dest.Path + $config.Directory.FullName.Replace($serverUNCPath,"")
    if(Test-Path -Path $config_target_dir){
        Copy-Item $config -Destination  $config_target_dir
    }
}
```

It fails with the message

```
Cannot find path 'D:\ServerDeploy\TestMachine1\website\web.config' because it does not exist.
At :line:39 char:12
+           Copy-Item <<<<  $config -Destination  $config_target_dir
```

The path `D:\ServerDeploy\TestMachine1\website` exists. I'm going mad over this.

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Eeeeh.... OK?

If I replaced the line

```
 Copy-Item $config -Destination  $config_target_dir
```

with

```
 Copy-Item $config.FullName $config_target_dir
```

it suddenly magically worked....

What gives?

Comment: Don't forget that you are dealing with actual objects in PS. Generally speaking when you hand an object to a cmdlet the cmdlets are pretty good at choosing the right property to work with. In this case you are handing a System.IO.FileSystemInfo.FileInfo object to the Copy-Item cmdlet. I think the cmdlet is probably defaulting to using the .Name property and that is not enough information for the copy to work. When you explicitly give the .FullName property to the cmdlet, it now has the information that it needs.

Comment: hmm, that would explain the error, but *not* the crappy errormessage. Why report as an error that the target location does not exist?

Comment: What's the current working directory at the time Copy-Item is executed?  My guess is it's D:\ServerDeploy\TestMachine1\website.  Like EBGreen said, Copy is treating $config as a relative path.  Thus, it thinks that (join-path (pwd) $config.Name) *is* the full source location.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it turns out to be a case sensitivity issue. My source path is in WSL which is case sensitive.